# CSS removing :hover properties

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of items which are alternating in background color via `:nth-child(even)`. The items are also highlighted with a different background color when the mouse hovers over them via `:hover`

I need to be able to specify items so that they maintain the alternating background color, *but do not get highlighted on hover*.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this.

Here is a short example: http://jsfiddle.net/kjk8L/2/

Comment: If you do not want items to be highlighted on hover, just delete the `ul li:hover` section of your CSS, or am I missing something?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kjk8L/4/

Comment: @DrydenLong, I don't want *certain* items to be highlighted (specified via and ID or class)

Comment: Then give the items you do want highlighted the same class and apply the style when you hover over that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it sounds (from your comment below) like you want to have a class that does not hover, but still maintains the alternating background.

Easiest way to do this is to simply define a class and exclude it from the hover css, like this:

```
ul li:not(.special):hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

This will make it so that hover is applied to everything except the 'special' class.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjk8L/8/)

Comment: Thanks, but this removes the highlight for *all* the grey items. I only want to remove the highlight for certain items (specified via and ID or class)

Comment: Excellent! I didn't even know about :not() Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a hover style to the nth-child(even) like this

```
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

see the updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/kjk8L/5/

Comment: Thanks, but this removes the highlight for *all* the grey items. I only want to remove the highlight for specified items.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, hope this helps.

```
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #efffef;
}

ul li:nth-child(even):hover {
    background-color: #dfd;
}

/* you can skip styling of the odd children if you don't want to */
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #efefff;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd):hover {
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```